# Full Turn Attacks, Two Weapon Fighting, and Path of War questions

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, skills, powers, two-weapon-fighting

Okay, I have a few questions about how exactly things stack and what happens. I'm new to Pathfinder and so is pretty much everyone else playing. The GM has played a little before but isn't an expert. We are use standard Pathfinder rules + *Path of War* expansion.

I wanted to know how many attacks I would get as a 16th level Warder (four attacks normally) with other things.

1. Full round attack is 4 attacks
2. Improved Two Weapon Fighting allows me two off hand strikes during a full round attack
3. *Broken Blade* Stance allows me two additional attacks if I have two weapons during a full round attack
4. *Finishing Kick* is a boost that allows for another unarmed attack at the end of full turn attack
5. *Raging Hunter Pounce* is a Martial Strike that allows for a charge attack into a full turn attack

During my turn, can I use a swift action to use *Finishing Kick* Boost, use full turn action to use *Raging Hunter Pounce* to make a charge attack that hits twice (one for each weapon), full turn attack from *Raging Hunter Pounce*, hitting four times for main hand and twice for off hand, gain two more attacks, one from each hand, from *Broken Blade* Stance, and finally finish off with *Finishing Kick* for a total of 6 main hand attacks, 4 off hand attacks, and one kick?

Comment: Have you found anything to suggest that your interpretation is wrong? Or are you just asking for verification?

Comment: Asking for verification.

Answer (score 2):

#### That is the correct interpretation of these abilities.

*Raging hunter pounce* gives you a full attack, which means that any abilities and effects you have that apply to full attacks apply here too.

However, I do want to note that *Path of War* is currently undergoing errata where the high amounts of damage, particularly from full attacking initiators, is being looked at and most likely nerfed. This is especially true regarding Broken Blade and Primal Fury, which are noted to be a bit overtuned compared to other disciplines. The errata is not yet finished and ready for playtesting/release, but it's something that I'd keep in mind.

Rules-wise, you're correct though.

Source: I'm the editor of *Path of War: Expanded*, and working on the errata for *Path of War*.

Comment: Follow up question, I found some stuff about charging. Can you use _Martial Charge_ (feat) and _Claw Pounce_ (Catfolk feat) together with _Raging Hunter Pounce_ to give you even more crazy damage?